# sockets and Hasmap objects

Tags: java, sockets, hashmap

So i was trying to make a server-client setup in a java project using eclipse.
details more or less irrelevant except that i was trying to pass an HashMap object back and forth.

I am able to do just that however when the server sent the first HashMap (HM1) the client would take in HM1 and act accordingly. however when another HashMap came in, the client did not receive HM2, but instead HM1, despite repeated verifications that server was indeed sending HM2 object.

i later resolved the issue by sending dos.ObjectOutputStream(HashMapObject.clone()) instead of just dos.ObjectOutputStream(HashMapObject) and now the client gets the right data.

bear in mind i have only tested by connecting to localhost for debugging.

now my question is, i do not understand why .clone() made the difference, can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Your statement of the problem is not consistent. HM1, HM2 and **HashMapObject**!?

Comment: i was using HM1 and HM2 as a way to show what was being sent and what was being received. I used HashMapObject as a generic term for when i was describing how i was sending the object as it was not important in describing what was sent when describing how i was using ObjectOutputStream method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `reset()` method on the `ObjectOutputStream` between writes.

This output stream type actually caches objects that it has written to save bandwidth if you end up writing the same object more than once. Calling `clone()` makes a difference because it's duplicating the object before sending. However, the output stream will cache those cloned objects too, which can become a memory issue pretty quickly.

Comment: good to know, i had tried reset, but didn't understand where the caching was happening, so i was trying to reset the input stream, now that i better understand the reset is working well for the output stream. thanks for the info.